# Is it possible to only load specific Annotations based on a profile?

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing

Is it possible to only load specific Annotations only during tests or only during a run in Spring Boot?

I am facing a situation where there are Annotations affecting the tests, yet work well in the live run, so wanted to know whether it was possible to exclude them only during tests, but include them when running, similar to how one can include specific beans based on a Spring profile

Apologies if this has been asked before, I have tried searching to no avail

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `@ConditionalOnProperty` annotation which creates a bean depending on which property (in the `application.properties` -> `app.val = false`) is set. For example for a service:

```
@Service
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "app.val", havingValue = "false")
public class TestService {
   ...
}
```

Also you could use the `@Profile` annotation and annotate them to the methods which have for example a test profile (defined in the `application.properties` as well -> `spring.profiles = test`).

```
@Profile({"test"})
public String getValue() {
    return "test value";
}
```

```
@Profile({"production"})
public String getValue() {
    return "production value";
}
```